# Error al utilizar pyautogui "NameError: name 'ImageGrab' is not defined"

Tags: python, pillow

```
import pyautogui
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save("screenshot.png")
```

al ejecutar este codigo me da este error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze__init__.py",
>   line 312, in _screenshot_win32
>       im = ImageGrab.grab()

[image: NameError: name 'ImageGrab' is not defined]

al parecer el error se da en el modulo pyscreeze en su ***init***, lo cual nose porque me da error, si pyscreeze viene pre-instalado y tengo los modulos pil y pillow.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi se puede ver el error, el cual nose porque se da, y porfa si tiene otra respuesta que no sea **from PIL import Image** porfa que me ayude ya que ya esta en el codigo de `___init___` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La segunda y tercera imagen son screenshots del codigo __init__ de pyscreeze por si las dudas :D

Comment: Curioso, yo al menos no puedo reproducir el error en Python 3.6 con Pillow 4.3.0,  PyAutoGUI 0.9.36 y PyScreeze 0.1.13 (todas actualizadas y en Windows por supuesto). ¿que ocurre si intentas importar tu mismo ImageGrab `from PIL import ImageGrab`?